# Error when installing RedBean using composer

Tags: php

When I start updating the composer, a token is required, what kind of token where can I get it?
Added a screenshot of the problem
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1Lu8.png)

Answer (score 0):

All info available on there GitHub page and they not recommending install via composer. Here i found few links that will help you to solve this. :)

[RedBean Github](https://github.com/gabordemooij/redbean)

[RedBean Manual](https://redbeanphp.com/manual3_0/index.php?p=/manual3_0/installing)

[RedBean Documentation : Install](https://redbean.dev/#install)